# Why does scss file import on Vite throws a MIME type error?

Tags: javascript, sass, path, vite, mime-types

I started to build a web app using Vite, Vanilla JS and SCSS. I installed "sass": "^1.69.5", "sass-loader": "^13.3.2".

The project structure is:

```
/index.html
|-- /src
|  |-- /app
|  |  | /app.js
|  |  | /app.scss
... other
```

Now, when I'm trying to do `import './app.scss';` from `app.js` I get this error:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server app.scss:1 responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I tried to comment `import './app.scss'. In this case the project builds without errors. I also tried to reinstall sass & sass-loader. I didn't help.

I noticed that when I just installed the project with `npm create vite@latest my-app -- --vanilla`, then installed SCSS dependencies and renamed the `css` file into `scss`, there was no such issue. Then, when I moved the `scss` file into `/src/app` the error appeared. So I believe the problem might be with the file path. But I'm not sure how to resolve it.